# Have a class init as a list object or a standard object

Tags: python, list, class

I have to convert a data structure to an object. This data structure can consist of any number of nested lists and dictionaries. I have written code that is currently capable of doing this as long as the input data is a dictionary on the highest level. if the input data is a list then this will not work because there is no initial key to create an attribute from. The functionality I'm looking for would have this class return a list if the input data is a list.

My current code is as follows:

```py
class DataConverter(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for key in data:
                value = data[key]
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    new_list = []
                    for ind in value:
                        if isinstance(ind, dict):
                            new_list.append(DataConverter(ind))
                        else:
                            new_list.append(ind)
                    setattr(self, key, new_list)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    setattr(self, key, DataConverter(value))
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, value)
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            new_list = []
            for val in data:
                new_list.append(DataConverter(val))
            # TODO: class needs to init as 'new_list' if it gets here
```

the input data will be in structures similar to this but 1000x larger and deeper:

```py
input_data = {
    "foo": "bar",
    "x": "y",
    "Something": 12345,
    "other": [
        {
            "yes": 1,
            "no": 0
        }
    ],
}
```

If I were to convert this data, I would expect the resulting object to be used like so:

```
>>> converted_data = DataConverter(input_data)
>>> converted_data.other[0].yes
1
```

This issue occurs when I get data structured like so:

```py
input_data = [
    {
        "foo": "bar",
    },
    {
        "x": "y",
    },
    {
        "Something": 12345,
    },
    {
        "other": [
            {
                "yes": 1,
                "no": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and I would expect this data to be used like so after conversion:

```
>>> converted_data = DataConverter(input_data)
>>> converted_data[3].other[0].no
0
```

I began writing something I imagined would work, but I can't figure out how to have the DataConverter object init as a list object if the input is a list.

### Answer

Based on JL Peyret's answer, I have added the factory method and changed a bit of code to make a better version.

```py
class DataConverter(object):
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        if isinstance(input_data, dict):
            for key, data in input_data.items():
                if isinstance(data, dict):
                    setattr(self, key, DataConverter(data))
                elif isinstance(data, list):
                    setattr(self, key, DataConverter.factory(data))
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, data)
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, data_input):
        if isinstance(data_input, dict):
            return DataConverter(data_input)
        elif isinstance(data_input, list):
            package = []
            for part in package:
                package.append(cls.factory(part))
            return package
```

The intended use is now

```
>>> obj = DataConverter.factory(input_data)
>>> obj[3].other[0].yes
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try to get too smart with the class `__init__` itself, rather use a factory method:

```
    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            return cls(data)
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            res = []
            for part in data:
                res.append(cls(part))
            return res
```

The whole code:

```
class DataConverter(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            for key in data:
                value = data[key]
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    new_list = []
                    for ind in value:
                        if isinstance(ind, dict):
                            new_list.append(DataConverter(ind))
                        else:
                            new_list.append(ind)
                    setattr(self, key, new_list)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    setattr(self, key, DataConverter(value))
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, value)
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            new_list = []
            for val in data:
                new_list.append(DataConverter(val))
            # TODO: class needs to init as 'new_list' if it gets here

    @classmethod
    def factory(cls, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            return cls(data)
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            res = []
            for part in data:
                res.append(cls(part))
            return res


input_data = {
"foo": "bar",
"x": "y",
"Something": 12345,
"other": [
    {
        "yes": 1,
        "no": 0
    }
],
}





input_data_list = [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
        },
        {
            "x": "y",
        },
        {
            "Something": 12345,
        },
        {
            "other": [
                {
                    "yes": 1,
                    "no": 0
                }
            ]
        }
        ]



converted_data = DataConverter.factory(input_data)
print (f"{converted_data.other[0].yes=}")

converted_data_list = DataConverter.factory(input_data_list)
print(f"{converted_data_list[3].other[0].no=}")
```

#### and output:

```
converted_data.other[0].yes=1
converted_data_list[3].other[0].no=0
```

Comment: This works fantastically. I didn't know anything about classmethods so this was a learning experience. There is only one downside to this method which is that each object now has the factory method within it, but its a small price to pay for working code. I'm going to update my question with the method I used based on your answer.

Comment: You’re welcome.  There is no inherent Python meaning to the name `factory` but thats usually how these types of methods are called so it facilitates communication.  One remark about making your own code more generic.  `new_list.append(DataConverter(ind)) `.   You could do this instead.  `cls = self.__class__` then `new_list.append(cls(ind)) ` so that you could subclass DataConverter if needed.  Btw, if you have more questions , consider asking a new one rather than overloading this one.

Comment: And factory isnt really tied to instances of your data in terms of memory use it’s strictly present *once* on the class.  It doesnt have to be either - my first draft factory was a standalone function with DataConverter hardcoded in it.  If your factory was tasked with looking at the data stream and decide on specialized DataConverter1 DataConverter2 DataConverter3 subclasses depending on data then it would probably be nice to consider a standalone function over a @classmethod.  But the basic idea is to keep it out of `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

I take the subdicts from the list and merge them in a larger dict until the list is exhausted, then we treat the dict as we would if it was given to `DataConverter` directly, by calling the class `__init__` which our newly created dict.

```py
elif isinstance(data, list):
    new_data = {}
    for subdict in data:
        new_data.update(subdict)
    self = self.__class__.__init__(self, new_data)
```

This is messy but is works. If someone has a better solution (probably using `super()`) I'm all ears.

Comment: This would break if the list is multiple nested lists, though this would work for the example given, I found it hard to explain just how veritable the input data could be. I could have 10 nested lists before finding my first dictionary. But this does introduce another idea i'm going to try out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a semi-valid approach but it results in a less than perfect solution.

```
class DataConverter(list):
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        if isinstance(input_data, dict):
            for key, data in input_data.items():
                if isinstance(data, list) or isinstance(value, dict):
                    setattr(self, key, DataConverter(value))
                else:
                    setattr(self, key, value)
        elif isinstance(input_data, list):
            for val in data:
                if isinstance(val, list) or isinstance(val, dict):
                    self.append(DataConverter(val))
                else:
                    self.append(val)
```

This results in an object that is a list of lists of lists of lis... etc. each list then has attributes added on if the data wasn't a list, but if the data is a list then we just continue onward as a list.

The only downside is that now each level of this object is a list, and will have list methods, But since I'm only using this object to read data, it shouldn't be a hindrance.

I would however like to know if there is a better way, this doesn't seem like the best way to me and I believe someone else with better knowledge of inheritance could figure this out.